# Creating stock.location based on field - Odoo v9 community

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9

I have this method, which should create a new `stock.location` every time a new car model is added to `fleet.vehicle` class in Odoo v9 community.

```
class fleet_vehicle(models.Model):
_inherit = 'fleet.vehicle'

@api.onchange('model_id')
def crear_location(self):
    self.env['stock.location'].search([('name', '=', self.model_id)])
    self.env['stock.location'].create({'name': self.model_id})
    return crear_location

location_id = fields.Many2one("stock.location", string="Almacén Origen", store=True, compute=crear_location)
```

But, the field on `fleet.vehicle` form is readonly, for some reason, I mean, I can't select, nor create anything, it's just there.

What am I missing here?

**EDIT**

I partially solved the issue by putting the attribute `readonly=False` on the `location_id` field, ut still, the `stock.location` isn't created whatsoever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three things that may cause the problems:

1/ onchange in Odoo only return warning,domain or values.
Refer to [this post](https://www.odoo.com/forum/how-to/developers-13/what-should-onchange-methods-do-and-return-57760) for more info

2/ location_id has 'compute' attribute, 'compute' often goes with @api.depends, not onchange. 
Please refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28270618/what-is-main-difference-between-api-onchange-and-api-depends-in-odooopenerp) for more explainations.

3/ In Odoo v9, self is recordset, you should use for loop to access single record

You should try your code like this (if using onchange, no need to use compute)

```
@api.onchange('model_id')
def crear_location(self):
    for record in self:
        location = self.env['stock.location'].search([('name', '=', record.model_id)])
        if not location:
            location = self.env['stock.location'].create({'name': record.model_id})
        record.location_id = location

location_id = fields.Many2one("stock.location", string="Almacén Origen")
```

Comment: Hi, very cool, but how it is created? Should I add this method to a button or something?, location_id field doesn't show anthing new and it doesn't creates the stock.location with this method, I think you are right, but how to use it? , sorry just wanting to know, Thank You again

Comment: That's why I was using compute, I know it wasn't right, but the location should be created when I save the record somehow, I'm just asking, should I open a new question?