# @api. depends or @api.onchange not working with compute field. why?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-12

In CRM module , in pipeline record, I have added one Float called `price_difference` with the help of inheritance. That field is difference between `planned_revenue` and `sale_amount_total` fields from the CRM module.

when I tired to use method name `get_price_diff()`,  it is not worked for me. I want to use `sale_amount_total` and `planned_revenue` with `@api.` depends or `@api.onchange`, but it is not working now.

Working of my method is simple, it depending upon `sale_amount_total`  and `price_difference` field. If any of the values changed, the method should run.

`sale_amount_total` is compute field in base module.

My code is below.
How to do it?

```py
class rate_record(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'crm.lead'

    price_difference = fields.Float(string='Price Difference', readonly=True)

    @api.onchange('sale_amount_total', 'planned_revenue')
    def get_price_diff(self):
        self.price_different = self.planned_revenue - self.sale_amount_total
```

Comment: Just use @api.multi for compute functions

Comment: Please add your view change (xml).

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do can't be achieved using api.depends or api.onchange only because it's not the way they work (see: [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28270618/what-is-main-difference-between-api-onchange-and-api-depends-in-odooopenerp)).

You can do it by using a compute method:

```
class rate_record(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'crm.lead'

    price_difference = fields.Float(
                           string='Price Difference', 
                           compute='get_price_diff')

    @api.depends('sale_amount_total', 'planned_revenue')
    def get_price_diff(self):
        self.price_different = self.planned_revenue - self.sale_amount_total
```

Answer (score 0):

I can only guess, because to this moment i don't have all information about your code. The onchange method `get_price_diff` looks right. But you set the field as `readonly=True`, and that means, the "computed" value won't be saved.

Since Odoo 11 you can force Odoo to save value changes on readonly marked fields with `force_save="1"` on it's field view definition:

```xml
<field name="price_difference" force_save="1" />
```

For older versions there are modules in the OCA repositories on Github. For example for Odoo 10 [web_readonly_bypass](https://github.com/OCA/web/tree/880df8eb7bb064079f795d474abf614f8afd31a0/web_readonly_bypass).

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
price_difference = fields.Float(string='Price Difference', readonly=True)
```

readonly=True - you won't be able to save this data price_difference.

Remove it, and test your code. Should work.

I had the same problem, it updates, but when I save it, it just disappears. Not sure if this is your problem, because your question is vague (what do you mean its not working now? Not saving the data? If this is the case, then my solution will work for you as it worked for me)